# Cannot use "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[Screenshot of Solution explorer with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEsBY.png)

Just recently, I have been trying out the new asp.net features and came across this error. I tried to use app.UseStaticFiles and added dependencies but for some reason It does not seem to compile?

The errors are :

[Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVdi3.png)

Project.json contains:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {

    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {

    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [

    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [

    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

output:

```
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\project.lock.json(1-1): DNX 4.5.1 error NU1006: Dependencies in project.json were modified. Please run "dnu restore" to generate a new lock file.
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\project.json(10,37,10,37): DNX 4.5.1 error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles >= 1.0.0-rc1-final could not be resolved.
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\project.lock.json(1-1): DNX 4.5.1 error NU1006: Dependencies in project.json were modified. Please run "dnu restore" to generate a new lock file.
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\project.json(10,37,10,37): DNX 4.5.1 error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles >= 1.0.0-rc1-final could not be resolved.
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\Startup.cs(23,17,23,31): DNX 4.5.1 error CS1061: 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseStaticFiles' and no extension method 'UseStaticFiles' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\project.lock.json(1-1): DNX Core 5.0 error NU1006: Dependencies in project.json were modified. Please run "dnu restore" to generate a new lock file.
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\project.json(10,37,10,37): DNX Core 5.0 error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles >= 1.0.0-rc1-final could not be resolved.
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\project.lock.json(1-1): DNX Core 5.0 error NU1006: Dependencies in project.json were modified. Please run "dnu restore" to generate a new lock file.
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\project.json(10,37,10,37): DNX Core 5.0 error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles >= 1.0.0-rc1-final could not be resolved.
1>C:\Users\sachinl\Desktop\TheWebApp\src\TheWebApp\Startup.cs(23,17,23,31): DNX Core 5.0 error CS1061: 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseStaticFiles' and no extension method 'UseStaticFiles' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Have you tried running dnu restore?

Comment: Yus, tried through command line and through manual, even tried reparing the asp.net......

Comment: Oh and if that fails, could you add your project.json `dependencies` and `frameworks` ?

Comment: What is the logging of the restore in the output window? The error refers to that.

Comment: what does the Output/Package Manager window say when you do a restore from inside VS?

Comment: It's saying package restore failed? while trying to restore it, check the first screen shot...

Comment: that's not the output window, that's the solution explorer.

Comment: My bad, I have pasted it on the description index as I have reached the limitation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`could not be resolved` during dnu restore usually means, it cannot find the NuGet package on the nuget feeds you have configured.

In Visual Studio, go into `Tools/Nuget Package Manager/Package Manager Settings` and check what's configured there.

It should have at least one entry pointing to nuget.org: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2

If that's there, you might have a nuget.config on the solution level. Check if there is a `nuget.config` file in your solutions folder or `\.Nuget` folder.

Comment: I don't have any .Nuget folder?, check the screenshot I have posted on my index...

Comment: that's fine, you should have one in C:\Users\<userName>\.Nuget which will be used globally. But you could have one locally (optionally) which could override what is defined globally.

Comment: Nope.... just checked There is no Nuget.config inside the NuGet folder.Is that file expected, if so do i manually add it??? Inside the folder there is Nuget.build, nuget.commandline, nuget.core

Comment: sorry, its in \AppData\Roaming\NuGet. And no you don't have to manually create it. Just use the nuget dialog from within Visual Studio and defined the feeds there

Comment: Found <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="Package source" value="C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Moq.4.0.10827" />
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
</configuration>

Comment: is there really a `;` semicolon after `value="nuget.org/api/v2/";`? Maybe that's why it doesn't work because its probably invalid xml?

Comment: Nice one, Just removing and adding new nuget folder link and restoring it,.....did the trick :), thanks mate